# How to fix the overflow hidden for bootstrap dropdown menu?

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am working on a project and it has a navbar. I'm using bootstrap library for styling my navbar, to make it more beautiful I added frosted glass effect. But after adding that effect to my navbar, due to `overflow:hidden` rule in my css file all the drop-downs are now half hidden. `overflow:hidden` is required as without this property that glass effect in not very good. Is there any way to keep both overflow property and make those drop-downs working perfectly as they were before adding this effect ?

html&css:

```css
body {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/0zi2FqA.jpg');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

nav {
  background: inherit;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: inherit;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2000px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  filter: blur(10px);
  margin: -10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">



<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand text-white">
         <img src="new.svg"width="60" height="60" class="rounded-circle"> BRAND
      </a>

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportContent">
         <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link signOutButton" href="#"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Sign Out</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item login dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Log In</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right text-center" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item googleButton">1</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item emailButton disabled" disabled>2</a>

        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item settings dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="settingsDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Settings</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right text-center" aria-labelledby="settingsDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item text-danger deleteAccount">1</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item text-primary info">2</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item text-primary addUrl">3</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider beforechangePass"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item text-primary changePass">4</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<br><br><br><br><br><br> <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><!-- for making scrollable -->
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/splintercell9/3rod6eua/13/)

**EDIT:** I wanted a solution that works on every devices whether it's small or big. Also some of the below answers are not good if your website is very large. At the time scrolling it breaks functionality of navbar somehow. I want to achieve this css effect without altering the main functionality of the Navbar across various devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**:
As requested, this should work:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    ul{
      position:fixed !important;
      right: 0;
      left: auto;
    }
}
```

This will make `ul` and it's children not be clipped. Therefore, `overflow:hidden` will not be applied to them. Also, this will align your elements to the right.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark navbar-fixed fixed-top">
```

This will make your navbar fixed on the top.

Comment: Thanks, now its working again on large screens but in small screens example mobile devices now their position has been changed.To fix that i have use `@media` rules with `min-width: 576px` so that devices with minimum width of 576px this css class will be applied otherwise it won't effect the toggling menu.

Comment: @splintercell9 you can fix your navbar as well. I'll edit my answer to attend to your request

Comment: Earlier I solved this issue by using my old answer inside @media for `max-witdth:576px` and answer provided below by using ::after class inside media rule for `min-width: 576px` but your has solved my problem with few lines of code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

there is another approach for solving your problem you can delete the `over-flow:hidden;` on your nav and also assign a height to your `nav::before` let it be 110px for example and then you can use this `nav::after` code to clear the borders of the blur effect

```css
body {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/IUWnlGU.jpg');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

nav {
  background: inherit;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  z-index: 999;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

nav::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: inherit;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2000px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  filter: blur(10px);
  /* assign a height*/
  height: 110px;
  margin: -10px;
   overflow: hidden;
}

/*the clear effect*/
nav::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height:30px;
  left:0;
  top:90px;
  width:100%;
  background: inherit;
}
```

Comment: It's good for large screen but for smaller screens it has some issue, so I think for both small and large devices now I have to put separate rules.

Comment: well you can replace the px units with percentages that will solve the responsive problem